# Public IP being assigned to EC2 Instance when an AD has been created

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-directory-services

I have created an EC2 Instance to host a web application on IIS.

Were using a directory service and hosting an domain account on there.

The app pools on IIS will use the domain account to authenticate to the RDS instance.

When I joined the domain to the instance it has given it a public IP.

Is there a reason why it automatically gives it a public IP? Ideally we want to keep this private.

Comment: Are you sure joining the domain to the instance is what triggered the public IP assignment? Generally your VPC subnet settings determine if a public IP is assigned.

Comment: There is an option called "Auto-assign Public IP" in the "Step 3: Configure Instance Details" section when launching an EC2 instance. You should just need to disable this option.